# opencart 1.5.1.3 how to edit text address line in checkout page

Tags: php, opencart

I am working on a project with opencart 1.5.1.3

On the checkout page, it shows the address in the billing tab. I want to edit the text to add a link

```
billing address +  (some link url)
```

Here the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to include a clickable link, this is probably better done by editing the template files, as opposed to through editing the Billing Address details.